# Simple Question for Powershell using html table

Tags: powershell

I have made my powershell script to extract and email some contents in a xml file. I used html and its table tag for email, and it works well. However, I want to add one more  on upper table header to show the title of table like the below table structure. How can I modify my code?
(Title of Table)--(lower table header)-->(name)(Consumers)(Enqueued)(Dequeued)(Checksum)

```
$tabName = “ActiveMq”
$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable “$tabName”

$col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Name",([string])
$col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Consumers",([string])
$col3 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Enqueued",([string])
$col4 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Dequeued",([string])
$col5 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Checksum",([int])

$table.columns.add($col1)
$table.columns.add($col2)
$table.columns.add($col3)
$table.columns.add($col4)
$table.columns.add($col5)

$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "admin" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ('admin', $pwd)
Invoke-RestMethod 'http://10.65.0.145:8161/admin/xml/queues.jsp' -cred $cred -Outfile 'E:\batch\queues.xml'

$Path = "E:\batch\queues.xml"
$xml2 = [xml](get-content $Path)
$xml2.Load($Path)
$targets = $xml2.SelectNodes("//stats")
  foreach($target in $targets) {
$addAtt = $xml2.CreateAttribute("name")
$addAtt.Value = $target.ParentNode.Name
$target.Attributes.Append($addAtt)
}
$xml2.Save("E:\batch\queues2.xml")

$xml = [xml]( Get-Content -Path 'E:\batch\queues2.xml' )
$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("//stats")
  foreach ($node in $nodes) {
$name = $node.attributes['name'].value
$consumerCount = $node.attributes['consumerCount'].value
$enqueueCount = $node.attributes['enqueueCount'].value
$dequeueCount = $node.attributes['dequeueCount'].value
$checksum = ($node.attributes['enqueueCount'].value) - ($node.attributes['dequeueCount'].value)

    $row = $table.NewRow()
    $row."Name" = ($name)
    $row."Consumers" = ($consumerCount)
    $row."Enqueued" = ($enqueueCount)
    $row."Dequeued" = ($dequeueCount)
    $row."Checksum" = ($checksum)   
    $table.Rows.Add($row)
}

$Head = @"
<style>
table {
border-collapse: collapse; width: 400px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; border: 1px solid #000000;
}

th {
border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center; padding: 6px; background: #d8d8d8; border: 1px solid #000000;
}

td {
border-collapse: collapse; text-align: left; padding: 6px; border: 1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
"@
[string]$body1 = [PSCustomObject]$table | select -Property "Name","Consumers","Enqueued","Dequeued", "Checksum" | Sort-Object -Property "Name" | ConvertTo-HTML -head $Head -Body "<font color=`Black`><br><h4>ActiveMQ</h4></font>"

Send-MailMessage -From 'myemail@gmail.com' -SmtpServer 10.65.0.40  -To youremail@gmail.com -Subject “Title" -body $body1 -BodyAsHtml
```

Comment: Have you made an effort to change the code yourself? If you've written the code you've posted, it should be relatively straightforward to make those changes. Can you post the code you've written and explain the specific problem you're having with that code? We're not a free code writing service. We're more than happy to help, but we do expect you to make an effort to do the work yourself first.

Comment: Did you take a look at the documentation of the `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet?